# Dropper, test for diamond

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am making a dropper mini game on my Minecraft server and I am using a button to give a player the diamond. I need a command block that sees if they have a diamond already so they don't get two diamonds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume they don't have diamond at first by adding a tag by default:

```
/scoreboard players tag @a add d
```

If they do have a diamond, remove the tag:

```
/scoreboard players tag @a remove d {Inventory:[{id:minecraft:diamond}]}
```

Give players that have the "d" tag a diamond:

```
/give @a[tag=d] diamond
```

Answer (score 2):

This can be done in just one command in Minecraft 1.13

```
/give @a[nbt=!{Inventory:[{id:"minecraft:diamond"}]}] diamond
```

Answer (score 1):

You can run a clear command and then give them the diamond

`/clear @p minecraft:diamond 1 0`

Then...
`/give @p minecraft:diamond 1 0 {display:{Name:"Optional Name"}}`